# Can I make it so when I hit reply on Thunderbird, focus is at the top and not bottom?

Tags: thunderbird

Whenever I push reply in Thunderbird, it gives focus to the end of the previous email.

I like to post all my replies above the previously sent email. Is there a way to do this by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools -> Account Settings -> select your account -> Composition & Addressing -> pick the reply position from the combo-box.